# Google Cloud Datastore Billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

```
gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" gs://${BUCKET}
```

Will google charge us for datastore read operations when we do datastore exports? We'd like to run nightly backups, but we don't want to get charged an arm and a leg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It may not be huge unless your table contains lots and lots of entities.

Refer to the table for pricing details. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing

Source:

Export and import operations are charged for entity reads and writes at the rates shown in the table above. If you cancel an export or import, you will be charged for operations performed up until the time that the cancel request has propagated through Cloud Datastore.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the pricing table and we're only looking at maybe $1.50 per night. Thanks for getting back to me so switfly